# minlength only in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, textinput, required, digits

Why is minlenght only working in Chrome?

[Example on JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xadry1r0/)

```
<form action=action" method="GET" class="search" onsubmit="javascript:return doSearch();">
<fieldset class="main">
  <input class="required digits" minlength="3" type="text" name="sPattern" id="someid" value="" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/18-minlength.html) no browser support that feature.

Nevertheless im on Chrome 40 and it works.

My personal recommendation: do not relay on HTML5 validation only, provide your form a JS Validation.